# How would society cope with a deformity that physically revealed all our secret vices?

Tags: humans, economy, politics

I'm writing a story about **a kind of plague that doesn't kill but instead reveals**.

This plague causes mottling (think spots of grey or brown) to appear on the skin whenever someone is in a state of strong desire or emotion. This already happens to people who have uncontrollable blushing when they are nervous or excited or whatever.

However, what I have in mind is that there are physical manifestations of our vices:

- Sexual desire causes a specific sort of mottling.
- Deception another.
- Arrogance another
- etc.

The more someone indulges in these vices, the more profound and chronic the transformation. You could know what someone's vices are just by looking at them. The plague is DNA based and I'm leaving a mystery why and where it came from.

**How would people cope with this new *normal*?** I'm interested in what sort of societal trends would emerge that I'm not thinking about.

I think some would mask the mottling by tattoos but it's on the face so I think masks might be worn when one needed to negotiate contracts etc. Furthermore I think there would be a lot less face to face interaction.

But I'm interested in creative speculation of what this would do with society.

Comment: What would be the impact of plastic surgery on the scarring?

Comment: no strong emotions and deceit?  Isn't that basically the drive behind vulcans and their 'logic'?

Comment: I dunno that it would change a whole lot. It's possible to tell blatant lies now. "[We are men of action. Lies do not become us](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x4czz9n)"

Comment: Did you see this Movie "The Invention of Lying" http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1058017/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_19

Comment: Questions that focus on "I change an aspect that's essential to our everyday life - how would society react?" are too broad most of the time. There would be no end to possible answers and the goal of StackExchange is to provide a Q&A where answers can be (somewhat) objectively rated against each other in a maximum of 30.000 characters (which is the **far** upper end). Your edits are in the right direction, but the part about "creative speculations" doesn't seem to fit if you ask me. Are there special aspects you are interested in? Conversations seem to be relevant to you. Could you narrow it?

Comment: Secespitus, you make a good point. I admit I am making this vague so that I don't reveal the plot of my novel. I think it may be futile for me to ask a question along these lines with enough detail to satisfy. Perhaps I will content myself with just looking at the other questions. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @J.k.Miles I understand that you don't want to give away your novel, but I think you don't need to. "Too broad" questions can almost always be reworded to be valid questions. Just make a sort of "series". You ask about one specific aspect, wait some time for ideas to come in and then ask the next question about a differenct specific aspect where you incorporate the feedback and ideas you get on the first question(s). Another tip: You can ping users with @<Username> so they see your comment (OP is always pinged; if there is only one person besides the OP he is automatically pinged).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you underestimate the power of self-deception. Lots of people would blithely go on lying, without being affected in the least and fully believing themselves sincere.

Surely this plague would result in large sales for make-up and "desensitizing" drugs - several antidepressants and antipsychotics might fit the bill; several neurotransmitter pathways are associated with the inability of feeling strong emotions.

Also, the forgotten virtue of ἀ-πάθεια would make a significant comeback, with self-help books and training courses galore.

One very likely side effect would be a general decline in the "humanity" of humanity. Pharmacological, training and traumatic anthagonization of the emotional response have all been related to reduced affect and [antisocial behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisocial_personality_disorder).

On a somewhat related note, you might be interested in checking out *The Primal Urge* by Brian W. Aldiss. There, a device will tell the world at large when one is sexually aroused. The world becomes much more interesting :-). In *The Quintaglio Ascension* by Robert J. Sawyer, the Quintaglios have chromatophores in their snouts that turn blue when lying, so that almost nobody even attempts to (and the world for "demon" means *those who can lie in the light of day*).

Comment: Pretty sure we could get into a giant argument about whether or not Trump and Hillary would be covered with sores or without a blemish.  Truth is relative.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Because this would be a new disease never before seen, a new branch of medicine and scientific research would quickly develop in order to understand the symptoms and causes. Although it would eventually become clear that deceit and strong emotion are involved, there is a tremendous complexity involved.

Variability:
As mentioned in another answer, there would be as much variation in expression of symptoms as there currently are for other skin conditions and diseases such as freckling, psoriasis, acne, and oily or dry skin problems. Some would be seen to be almost non-existent, or mere nuisance symptoms, while others would be so dramatic as to cause severe psychological trauma to the sufferer, and based on the level of deceit expresssed by different individuals.

Motives: 
Since people lie for many different reasons, not all of which are bad, or at least would be understandable and likely to be done by the vast majority of people, I agree it absolutely would not stand up in a legal court. In the court of public, however, there would possibly be an "ist" against those with higher than usual symptoms...at least at first. As additional discoveries are made about the process and progress of the condition, and of course the wide-spread prevalence of symptoms,  stereotypes will likely fade or morph into more specific forms.

Rebels:
In many societies, there are some who like to push the limits of  the current societal norms. There could easily arise different groups that for whatever creed they follow, would wear their mottling and deformities with pride. They could even over time gain notoriety. If science discovers the effects are reversible, this response would be especially attractive to teenagers and young adults.  If not easily reversible, it may be like tattooing once was viewed: as inappropriate for the general population.  As some of these folks grow and change through experiences, they might later regret their rash decisions of youth, and look for surgical alterations.

Therefore secondary medical and holistic professionals would also develop to deal with the psychological issues and with reversal techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Society as we know would collapse. Jobs that require lying would either be very high paid or done by the desperate. Doctor visits and schools would be hell. THose who comfort a child with a small lie (You'll be okay) would now suffer each time they did.

Advertisement will either diminish or be taken over by cheaper workers. Interesting advertisement would fade in the latter. Being replaced with simple models that have proven to work.

Long term I'd say the toll on medical personal and first responders would be terrible. They'd be as marked if not more then petty criminals. Undercover cops and the like would fit right in with their lying. But only for a short while because they would rack up scarring much faster.

I'm not sure people would start to wear masks. Given the broad definition of what causes the mottling I'd say everyone will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

We already give out lots of involuntary signals about our emotions.  Very few people can control them.  It might make it easier to tell, but then would the changes in skin be consistent between different people ?  It's only useful if e.g. everyone turns blue.  It's actually problematic if the majority are affected in one way and a minority are affected differently.

If the effects were not consistent from person to person, then it would simply complicated communication.  It could even lead to discrimination or racism of different kinds.  Perhaps I'd be discriminated against because I turn green when telling the truth instead of turning green when I'm lying, like the majority.  Human biochemistry is complex, so I'd expect exceptions to the norm.

I'd expect full body clothing to become popular.  I've seen this in pro poker.  Many players now try and wear dark glasses, and cover their faces and necks in various ways to minimize clues that people can pick up about whether they're nervous or faking nervousness or whatever.  This might become a trend.

But let's assume for a moment there are no differences from person to person : everyone is affected the same way consistently.

Does that help us ?  Probably not.  Much of our social norms actually do operate on lying.  At the very least the transitional generation that has not learned to "maneuver" in the new scenario would find it very difficult.  For example, how do you deal with your boss when your skin says flat out you're angry as hell or lying and the boss and you are both socially adapted to living the lie that we're all on the same side, and egos are at stake ?  How many marriages (happy ones) would survive not being able to get away with those little white lies (yes, I think you look great in that.  No I don't think you're getting fat.  Bald ? - not easy for a generation used to expecting the lie to get used to the truth, I think).

And would it reduce crime ?  Probably not.  Many criminals are lousy liars anyway (ask a police officer), and it's not the lack of knowing they're lying that allows crime to continue, but the lack of evidence.  And we'd still need evidence.  Looking like you're lying would be no more useful as evidence than a signed confession without evidence.

Would it make politics and business honest ?

I have a feeling that it would not.  There's a lot at stake and I suspect that the people driven to rise to the top would hardly feel a thing when they lie.  I suspect you'd not see any reaction from their skin.  But even if it did, there's a lot at stake financially and in terms of power and I think we'd see them learn to lie (it's a skill).

And if lying gives an advantage, I'm afraid I'm cynical enough to think we'd find ways to allow it to continue being done.  We already bend over backwards to reward people for lyings and deception in business : no one ever got a bonus for being an honest CEO and never mind the dividend.

There's an old trick about lying : first you tell as much of the truth as you can, and when you lie you lie in the smallest way possible.  That way, when you do have to tell a big lie, it's both easier to do and less likely to be considered as a lie.

Which brings us to the last issue.

Would we accept that someone is lying based on what we see happen their skin ?

Lies are often accepted not because they're actually in any way convincing, but because they're what we (the one being lied to) want to believe.  How many people have gotten away with "Honey, I didn't have sex with them, you've got to believe me", despite a truckload of evidence against them and a track record of lying ?  We believe what we want to believe and we're really good at ignoring things that we want to on some level.  We rationalize the irrational.  We make excuses for other people.

I don't think it would make as much difference as we'd initially think it might.

Most likely outcome : we dress differently to enable us to continue lying.